# Ruby, get duration in seconds from time

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have an `ISO8601` time duration, like `TM1M10S`. I would simply like to know how many seconds that duration is with Ruby (in this case its 70s).

Edit: Ups, I meant `PT1M10S`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Output Ruby duration in iso8601](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9520988/output-ruby-duration-in-iso8601)

Comment: I don't think `TM1M10S` is a valid ISO 8601 format.

Comment: I don't know why `Date::_iso8601 'TM1M10S'` is not working.. It gives me `{}`... Even one date I took from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601), that's also not working - `Date::_iso8601  "P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S" #=> {}`

Comment: `P3Y6M4DT12H30M5S` is a duration, not a time or a date. You will not be a able to parse this with the Ruby Date or Time classes. Either look for a library to do this, or write your own parser.

Comment: @DouglasFShearer ah! that's true..

Comment: Ruby does not have a native class for durations. It uses normal numbers to represent seconds.

Answer (score 2):

One option, I found this just now so YMMV, but there seems to be an [iso8601 gem](https://rubygems.org/gems/iso8601)

Quickly running in IRB after grabbing the gem:

```
require 'iso8601'
ISO8601::Duration.new('PT1M10S').to_seconds
=> 70.0
```

Comment: Thanks. I found this gem too xD